# Access 10th through 70th element in STRUCT

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 3 fields: username, tracking_id, timestamp. One user will have multiple rows (some have more, some have less) with different tracking ids and timestamps for each action he has taken on my website. I want to group by the username and get the tracking ids of that user's 10th through 70th action. I use standard SQL on BigQuery.

First problem is, I can't find syntax to access a range in the STRUCT (only a single row or using a limit to get the first/last 70 rows for example). Then, I can image after managing to access a range, there could be an issue with the index being out of bounds because some users might not have 70 or more actions.

```
SELECT
  username,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(tracking_id,
      timestamp)
  ORDER BY
    timestamp
    )[OFFSET (9 to 69)] #??????
FROM
  table
```

The result should be a table with the same 3 fields: username, tracking_id, timestamp, but instead of containing ALL the user's rows, it should only contain each users 10th to 70th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT username, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(tracking_id, `timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS selected_actions
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(pos) FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY `timestamp`) pos
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ) 
  WHERE pos BETWEEN 10 AND 70
)
GROUP BY username
```